# A smooth univariate function $f$ with vanishing first and second derivative, but neither an inflection nor extremum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Can we find a smooth univariate function $f$ at $x=x_0$ where

- $f'(x_0)= f''(x_0)=0 $
- $x_0$ is not an inflection point
- $x_0$ is not a local extremum.

Comment: Suggestion: make it wiggle a lot at $0$.

Comment: What have you tried?